# Setting a maximum number for a label in PowerPoint-VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub PlusOne()
counter.Caption = (counter.Caption) + 1
End Sub
Sub MinusOne()
counter.Caption = (counter.Caption) - 1
End Sub
```

Above is the Visual Basic Code which I use for a PowerPoint Scoreboard (to increase +1 or -1 in the label).

How do I add a maximum number which can be increased in the label.
If I press the shape containing `Sub PlusOne` the label will increase indefinitely.

How do I set a maximum number which a label can display.. let us take 150.

Basically, I want the number of the label to increase upto 150 only.

Comment: What kind of label? Data label?

Comment: Perhaps If counter.Caption > 150 Then counter.Caption = 150

Comment: ``Sub PlusOne()
If counter.Caption < 150 Then
counter.Caption = (counter.Caption) + 1
Else
counter.Caption = 150
End Sub``

This doesn't work. I use the label which is present in the Developer Tab in PPT

Comment: Microsoft forms label ?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me if I am using a Microsoft Forms 2 Label.

I am holding the current value of the label in a public variable. Also, I have added a public constant for the max number to make it easy to adjust.

I used the syntax from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/605606-run-macro-multiple-times.html) to determine how to set up a testing construct of running the `test` sub multiple times i.e. loop using the file name and sub name with `Application.Run`.

```
Option Explicit 
Public currVal As Long
Public Const maxValue As Long = 150

Public Sub RunTest

    Dim i As Long
    currVal = 0

    Do While i < 152 'change to test

        Application.Run "'Presentation1.pptm'!test" ' where it is name of presentation and name of sub

    Loop

    Msgbox currVal

End Sub

Public Sub test()

    Dim myLabel As Label

    Set myLabel = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Label1").OLEFormat.Object

    If currVal < maxValue Then CurrVal = CurrVal + 1

    myLabel.Caption = currVal

End Sub
```